# what's the diffrence between these three sentences if indeed there's any

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

> 1. She was fortunate to escaped Hitler's Germany with her life

> 2. She was fortunate to have escaped Hitler's Germany with her life

> 3. She was fortunate to escape   Hitler's Germany with her life

Comment: (1) is ungrammatical, the others are both valid. (3) refers to her good luck at the time of escaping, (2) to her subsequent life.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is ungrammatical. "To escaped" doesn't exist in English.

We have these forms of infinitive:

General forms - to escape, to be escaping, to be escaped

Perfect forms - to have escaped, to have been escaping, to have been escaped

And of course bare infinitive "Escape", but you can't use that in your sentence.